# Ubuntu 18.04 all keys, taps unresponsive but cursor moves

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad

Ubuntu 18.04 w/kernel 4.19.9
Frequently I find, usually while web browsing, that my keyboard keys are no longer recognized when pressed, and that the touchpad
tapping no longer works.   However, I can move the cursor with the touchpad OR with an added mouse though that mouse, if connected, has also lost it's ability to click R or L.  I've researched a pile of similar issues people are having w/18.04 but not seeing any answers yet or their issues are not exactly like mine.  I can cold boot only at this point and upon restart, may be able to work for awhile or it might happen again soon.  I've run Mate Monitor to see whether the processor is being tied up or out of memory but not seeing anything here.  Any pointers as to a course of diagnostics or bug info would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Check your memory!

Comment: Can you be for specific George.

Answer (score 0):

I found that upgrading to kernel 4.20 seemed to solve the issue (I hate to use the term "upgrade" usually when it comes to "newer" with respect to computers and systems!)